# How to convert pd.series to np.array, not array of arrays? How to replace nan values?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

I struggle to convert selected data from a pd.df to a np.array. Instead I get an array of arrays. I would like to now why I don't get back immediately a normal array, please. I am aware of `to_numpy()`, but it does not result in the desired outcome. Neither can I replace the nan values. Could you please help me to understand, what is going on, please? Thanks a lot! Have a nice day.

My mini example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#prepare the example
d={}
d['key1']=np.array([np.nan,2,np.nan,4])
d['key2']=np.array([5,6,7,8])                 
d['key3']=np.array([9,10,11,12])       
print(d)
print(type(d))

# create example df
df=pd.DataFrame(index=[0,1,2,3,4,5],columns=['A','B'])
df.at[0,'A'] = d
df.at[1,'A'] = d
df.at[2,'A'] = d
df.at[3,'A'] = d
df.at[4,'A'] = d
df.at[5,'A'] = d

df

# extract data from selected rows
res1=df.loc[[1,2,3],'A'].apply(lambda x: x.get('key2')).to_numpy()
print(res1)
print(res1.shape) #(3,)
#res1 is an object filled with arrays.
#Why would I not get back immediately an array (3,4), please?

#How can I get a np.array like this, please?
#res2=np.array([[5, 6, 7, 8],[5, 6, 7, 8],[5, 6, 7, 8]])
#res2.shape #(3,4)

# The solution I found:
res3=np.stack(res1,axis=0)
print(res3)
print(type(res3))
print(res3.shape)
#Is there something better that results immediately in a np.ndarray with (3,4)?

#How can I replace the nan values, please?
res4=df.loc[[1,2,3],'A'].apply(lambda x: x.get('key1')).to_numpy(na_value=0)
print(res4) #nan not 0
```

Thank you.

Edit: I clarified the second question. I would just like to replace the nan's with 0, for example. In the real world example not all arrays for key1 contain a nan. I need to keep the number of elements in each array the same. Sorry. Does somebody understand why my example does give the desired result? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
res4=df.loc[[1,2,3],'A'].str['key1'].values
#instead of using apply() and lambda use .str['key name'] to get a value of particular key
res4=np.vstack(res4)
#it's similar to np.stack() at axis=0
#Finally:
res4=np.where(pd.isna(res4),0,res4)
```

output of `res4`:

```
array([[0., 2., 0., 4.],
       [0., 2., 0., 4.],
       [0., 2., 0., 4.]])
```

**Explaination to your question:**

The values that you are getting are the Series of numpy's array:

```
df.loc[[1,2,3],'A'].str['key1']
#output:
1    [nan, 2.0, nan, 4.0]
2    [nan, 2.0, nan, 4.0]
3    [nan, 2.0, nan, 4.0]
Name: A, dtype: object
```

You can check that by mapping type:

```
df.loc[[1,2,3],'A'].str['key1'].map(type)
#output:
1    <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
2    <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
3    <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
Name: A, dtype: object

#OR  
#just by:

df.loc[[1,2,3],'A'].str['key1'].values

#output:
array([array([nan,  2., nan,  4.]), array([nan,  2., nan,  4.]),
       array([nan,  2., nan,  4.])], dtype=object)
```

you will get arrays of array

**Note:** the `na_value` parameter in `to_numpy()` method doesn't work because the values inside your Series are stored in container(np.array in your case)

Also It will not work in case of `list`,`tuple` and `set` because they are also containers(or you can say data structures)

If the values are not stored in a container then `na_value=0` will work

consider the following example:

```
s=pd.Series([5,4,7,np.nan,np.nan])
#Let's say I have this Series
df=pd.DataFrame(data=[[5,4,np.nan,np.nan,6],[2,np.nan,5,np.nan,7]]).T
#And this dataframe
#So the values inside Series and Dataframe are not stored in a container(the datatype is float)
```

Now I can easily use `na_value` parameter of `to_numpy()` method:

```
s.to_numpy(na_value=0)
#output of above code:
array([5., 4., 7., 0., 0.])
df.to_numpy(na_value=0)
#output of above code:
array([[5., 2.],
       [4., 0.],
       [0., 5.],
       [0., 0.],
       [6., 7.]])
```

**Update:**

As I mentioned above the `na_value` parameter in `to_numpy()` method doesn't work because the values inside your Series are stored in container(np.array in your case)

you are getting an **array of values(array is a container that is holding values)** from the dict with key 'key1'

Consider the following example:

```
d={}
d['key1']=np.array([np.nan,2,np.nan,4])
d['key2']=np.array([5,6,7,8])                 
d['key3']=np.array([9,10,11,12])       
d1={}
d1['key1']=np.nan
d1['key2']=np.array([5,6,7,8])                 
d1['key3']=np.array([9,10,11,12]) 
df=pd.DataFrame(index=[0,1,2,3],columns=['A','B'])
df.at[0,'A'] = d
df.at[1,'A'] = d
df.at[2,'A'] = d1
df.at[3,'A'] = d1
```

Now if you use `na_value` parameter you will get:

```
df['A'].str['key1'].to_numpy(na_value=0)
#output:
array([array([nan,  2., nan,  4.]), array([nan,  2., nan,  4.]), 0, 0],
      dtype=object)
                                           ^nan are not filled because they are inside the container(np.array)                      
                                                                ^nan fill with 0
```

**Note:**

If the Series contains real dict then you can use `str['keyname']` notation to get the values of that key in a Series and ofcourse It is faster than `apply()` and anonymous function

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  This seems also a way to do this. Could you help me to understand better this `to_numpy()` function in case you have used it, please? See my comment about it above. Thank you very much for this discussion.

Comment: @PythonSmurf updated answer....kindly have a look ***:)***

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. You mean `to_numpy` cannot convert `na_values` because data originates from a dict key:value pair? Sorry, I did not realise this from reading the doc-page of `to_numpy()`. 
May I ask why use `.str` to get to the content? Is this better than `apply(lambda x: x.get('key1')).to_numpy(copy=True)`? Thanks for your patience and sharing your knowledge.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. It seems difficult to discover this is an container, when it says np.array. Or is this visible through `dtype=object`? I thought it was a normal np.array. Would it not be better if an error is raised, indication nothing was replaced?

Comment: @PythonSmurf If you readed  answer carefully then I have mention that how to check if it is a container or not...and also `na_value` is an optional parameter

Comment: Hi. Thank you. Yes, you wrote "by mapping type". I see in your example thrice `<class 'numpy.ndarray'>` but I am not able to spot the container. Maybe via `object`?

Answer (score 1):

#### First question

Calling `to_numpy()` then `np.stack()` seems like the right answer, I can't think of a better or shorter way to do it.

#### Second question

I'm assuming you want to replace NaNs with zeroes, not remove the values (and change the shape). The following code does it:

```
res4 = df.loc[[1,2,3],'A'].apply(lambda x: x.get('key1')).to_numpy()
res4 = np.stack(res4)
np.where(np.isnan(res4), 0, res4)
```

`np.isnan` produces a boolean mask with identical shape, and `np.where` puts 0 where it finds True, otherwise it keeps the value from `res4`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am still unsure if I have understood `to_numpy()` correctly. Why does this function return such a strange numpy ndarray full of arrays?
Here is its definition: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_numpy.html?highlight=to_numpy
One of the option in this function is also `na_value=`. Should I not be able to replace  NaNs with it in one go while converting from df to np.ndarray? 
It also lists a table with dtype options, but I did not understand how it works either. Maybe this is a way to get a more normal np.ndarray instead of dtype object?